# XV6: pwd implementation

Tags: xv6

I was trying to implement pwd command in xv6 system. But i am getting a error in sysfile.c execution. The function is as follows showing the error:-

```
int sys_getcwd(void) {
    char *p;
    int n;
    if(argint(1, &n) < 0 || argptr(0, &p, n) < 0)
       return -1;
    return name_for_inode(p, n, proc->cwd);
}
```

I get error as follows:

```
error: ‘proc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
return name_for_inode(p, n, proc->cwd);
```

But I also included proc.h in this file.

Comment: Please do not post an image of an error trace. Instead, edit your question and post the code of the problematic function (`sys_getcwd`). See also [ask]

Answer (score 2):

`proc` is not defined, and warning, it's a `struct` name.

You have to query the current process, you can do it with `myproc()` function

```
int sys_getcwd(void) {
    char *p;
    int n;
    struct proc *curproc = myproc();

    if(argint(1, &n) < 0 || argptr(0, &p, n) < 0)
       return -1;

    return name_for_inode(p, n, curproc->cwd);
}
```

Comment: @MSD If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes proc is not global variable so initialize it with current process on which cpu is working.

```
struct proc *proc = myproc();
return name_for_inode(p, n, proc->cwd);
```